# Move one matchstick to create a three-letter word

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

On a table, you have several matchsticks as arranged below. Your objective is to move a single matchstick to create a three-letter word.

[image: Matchsticks]

Which matchstick do you move, and how do you move it?

Comment: rot13(Vs V zbir bar, fgevxr vg naq hfr vg gb frg gur bguref ba sver, V znxr N-F-U) or is that too lateral? :)

Comment: @SteveV rot13: `Abg gbb yngreny ng nyy. Gung jnf dhvpx` :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can do it by

> moving one, striking it and using it to set the others on fire

Then

> I make A-S-H

Comment: I realize that these sort of puzzles usually rely on such tricks, but the instructions "to move a single matchstick to create a three-letter word" are a bit more than just misleading were this the answer.
We've done more than "move" a single matchstick (requiring a striking strip to activate, then moving it back to the whole) and we haven't created a three-letter word, but instead a material, ash, destroying all matchsticks in the process.
It's certainly possible to tweak the objective to specifically allow this result to match, currently the objective as written seems too restrictive.

Comment: This isn’t true. If you’ve ever burned a matchstick, you’ll know that they burn down to char but not to ash. You need  a more confined and hotter fire for that.

Answer (score 3):

I think one should move the

> upper left matchstick into the bottom right position (rotating it by 90 degrees)

in order to get

> *Six* equal squares.
>  [image]
>  Six is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Comment: isn't that actually 7 squares though?

Comment: that's correct, i fixed it, thanks.